# Regular Expression to find hidden fields in html

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to find all input fields of type hidden in html output. Anyone know an expression to do such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the link Radomir suggest is correct that HTML should not be **parsed** with regular expressions. However, I **do *not*** agree that nothing meaningful can be gleaned from their use together. And the ensuing rant is totally counter-productive.

To correct Robert's RegEx:

`<([^<]*)type=('|")hidden('|")>[^<]*(/>|</.+?>)`

Comment: Not even close. For example, try `<input type =hidden name =surname value =smith>` or `<input type=text name=info value="type='hidden's how to carry data between pages." >`. And both of those examples are valid html. Never mind the problems when processing real world html.  Use a parser.

Comment: @Alohci, *no doubt* you should use a parser if you can for ANYTHING xml. @Niall, if you need the optional spaces in the expression to handle the cases Alohci brought up, it shouldn't be too hard. Ugly, yes, but not too hard.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for regular expression, but download [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and do the following:

```
var inputs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input");
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
   if( input.Attributes["type"].Value == "hidden" )
   // do something
}
```

You can also use xpath with html agility pack.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are generally the wrong tool for the job when trying to search or manipulate HTML or XML; a parsing library would likely be a much cleaner and easier solution.

That said, if you're just looking through a big file and accuracy isn't critical, you can probably do reasonably well with something like `<input[^>]*type="?hidden"?`.

Comment: ngroot, that expression is only a partial match.

Comment: That's correct.  He asked for an expression that would find these tags, which this will usually do.  What's it matter if it matches on the whole tag?

Comment: I don't think finding *half* of the tag will really help, but I see your point. It won't let me un-down-vote you though.

Comment: Half the tag is just fine if you are, as the author requested, just looking to *find* the tags.  That's what I usually do if I'm doing ad-hoc searches of documents; I use the shortest expression that will take me to what I'm looking for.  If he wants to do something more complex, like replace them, a regex is really not a safe tool to be using anyway.